# Context API doesn't pass data properly

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to learn React's hooks and I have some problems with the way that Providers are passing its data to my components.

I have AuthContex, UsersContext, LanguagesContext and WordsContext.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthProvider>
      <UsersProvider>
        <LanguagesProvider>
          <WordsProvider>
            <App />
          </WordsProvider>
        </LanguagesProvider>
      </UsersProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

AuthContext and UsersContext are perfectly fine.

WordsContext returns its state correctly but throws a "TypeError: getWord is not a function" when I try to invoke getWord().

LanguagesContext returns "undefined" when I try to use "language" despite the fact that its value is set to "English" and also throws the "TypeError" when I invoke getLanguage().

To make it more visual:

```
export const Languages = () => {

  const { getLanguage, language } = useContext(LanguagesContext)
  const { getWord, word } = useContext(WordsContext)
  const { getUser, user } = useContext(UsersContext)

  const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
  const userId = localStorage.getItem('id')

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser(token, userId) // Works fine
    getWord(token, 1) // throws TypeError: getWord is not a function
    getLanguage(token, 1) // throws TypeError: getLanguage is not a function
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {user ? user.name : null} {/* Works fine */} 

      {language} {/* Returns undefined despite being set to "English" in state */} 

      {word} {/* Returns state value but getWord() throws an error */} 
    </div>
  )
}
```

I guess that functions throw an error because they are both returned as "undefined" from the context, but I have absolutely no idea what may cause this problem.

WordsContext:

```
const initialState = {
  word: 'Example',
  errors: null
}

export const WordsContext = createContext(initialState)

const port = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

const version = 'v1'

export const WordsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(WordsReducer, initialState)

  async function getWord(token, word_id) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": token
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${port}/${version}/words/${word_id}`, config)

      dispatch({
        type: GET_WORD,
        payload: res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: FAIL,
        payload: err
      })
    }
  }

  return (<LanguagesContext.Provider value={{
    word: state.word,
    erros: state.errors,
    getWord,
  }}>
    {children}
  </LanguagesContext.Provider>)
}
```

LanguagesContext:

```
const initialState = {
  language: 'English',
  errors: null
}

export const LanguagesContext = createContext(initialState)

const port = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'

const version = 'v1'

export const LanguagesProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(LanguagesReducer, initialState)

  async function getLanguage(token, languageId) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": token
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${port}/${version}/languages/${languageId}`, config)

      dispatch({
        type: GET_LANGUAGE,
        payload: res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: FAIL,
        payload: err
      })
    }
  }

  return (<LanguagesContext.Provider value={{
    language: state.language,
    erros: state.errors,
    getLanguage,
  }}>
    {children}
  </LanguagesContext.Provider>)
}
```

Comment: Did you use `LanguagesContext.Provider` inside WordsContext in your App too or its just a typo in the post . Because if its actually in your code, that could be the issue

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Yes, that's actually an issue... Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly used `LanguagesContext.Provider` instead of `WordsContext.Provider` in your `WordsProvider` which causes the conflict with `LanguagesContext` and because of that `WordsContext` also doesn't work

```
export const WordsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(WordsReducer, initialState)

  async function getWord(token, word_id) {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        "Authorization": token
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.get(`${port}/${version}/words/${word_id}`, config)

      dispatch({
        type: GET_WORD,
        payload: res.data
      })
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch({
        type: FAIL,
        payload: err
      })
    }
  }

  return (
   <WordsContext.Provider value={{
    word: state.word,
    erros: state.errors,
    getWord,
  }}>
    {children}
  </WordsContext.Provider>
  )
}
```